Can __attribute__ ((packed)) create a 1-bit struct when the only member is a bit-field?
I was reading through the documentation of GNU/GCC and I stopped at the description of __attribute__ ((packed)).
It says:

packed
The packed attribute specifies that a variable or structure field should have the smallest possible alignment—one byte for a variable, and one bit for a field, unless you specify a larger value with the aligned attribute.
Here is a structure in which the field x is packed, so that it immediately follows a:
struct foo
{
    char a;
    int x[2] __attribute__ ((packed));
};


I wonder how this attribute works exactly and whether this code:
struct bar
{
    char a:1 __attribute__ ((packed));
};

would create a 1-bit structure instead of 1-byte.

sizeof(foo) is an integer

The quoted text says one byte for a variable. This struct foo var; is a variable.

Key statement is: "smallest possible alignment". Alignment refers to bytes not bits.

A byte is the smallest addressable unit.  As such, structs can only occupy a whole number of bytes, not fractional bytes.
Any unused bits in bitfields (or more accurately, the storage units containing bitfields) become padding.
So in your example of struct bar, the size of the struct will still be 1, with 1 bit used and 7 bits unused.

It's worth noting that even an empty struct is at least one byte large. If that cannot be less than a byte large, then something containing a bit-field surely can't either. I'm curious about putting a packed "one-bit struct" into another packed struct that has a bit-field.

So, it wouldn't have any significant impact on struct bar?

@Glitch Correct, see edit.

@JanSchultke I believe that's only for C++.  gcc shows that such a struct has size 0.  I suspect defining such a struct is UB in C, but so far I haven't found a definitive statement of that.

@JanSchultke Empty struct is at least one byte in C++ but not in C. In C++ different objects must have different addresses.

@dbush: Re “definitive”: C 2018 6.2.6.1 2, “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes…”, and C 2018 6.7.2.1 8, “…  If the struct-declaration-list does not contain any named members, either
directly or via an anonymous structure or anonymous union, the behavior is undefined…”

@EricPostpischil Thanks, I was going to suggest struct { int :0; } as a valid type until you pointed that out!

"A byte is the smallest addressable unit." --> Hmmm, perhaps a graphics processor with an address for each bit could point to something narrower than 8 bits, yet the C model does not readily support such.
